# How can I determine the purity of an oligonucleotide solution?

Tags: chromatography, purification

After desalting an oligonucleotide via gel chromatography, I am left with (presumably) an oligonucleotide substance suspended in a buffer. What is the simplest way to verify the oligonucleotide's purity to make sure the desalting process was successful?